# Вывести следующие записи из массива

Tags: php, битрикс24

Есть массив

```
Array
 (
   [result] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 272
                [NAME] => 3D Crocodile
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 274
                [NAME] => A.Lange & Sohne
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 76
                [NAME] => Adidas
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 276
                [NAME] => Amber
            )

        [4] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 18
                [NAME] => AMST
            )

        [5] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 48
                [NAME] => Anna Klein
            )

        [6] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 60
                [NAME] => Armani
            )

        [7] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 278
                [NAME] => Audemars Piguet
            )

        [8] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 280
                [NAME] => Audi
            )

        [9] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 282
                [NAME] => Baellerry
            )

        [10] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 284
                [NAME] => Bailini
            )

        [11] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 254
                [NAME] => Baosaili
            )

        [12] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 286
                [NAME] => BMW
            )

        [13] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 288
                [NAME] => Bokesi
            )

        [14] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 290
                [NAME] => Breguet
            )

        [15] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 42
                [NAME] => Breitling
            )

        [16] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 292
                [NAME] => Burberry
            )

        [17] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 64
                [NAME] => Bvlgari
            )

        [18] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 66
                [NAME] => Calvin Klein
            )

        [19] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 294
                [NAME] => Carsidun
            )

        [20] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 246
                [NAME] => Cartier
            )

        [21] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 296
                [NAME] => Casio
            )

        [22] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 300
                [NAME] => Casio Shors
            )

        [23] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 248
                [NAME] => Cerrutti
            )

        [24] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 78
                [NAME] => Chanel
            )

        [25] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 80
                [NAME] => Chopard
            )

        [26] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 82
                [NAME] => Citizen
            )

        [27] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 84
                [NAME] => Coach
            )

        [28] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 86
                [NAME] => Ctuss
            )

        [29] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 88
                [NAME] => Curren
            )

        [30] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 90
                [NAME] => Devis
            )

        [31] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 40
                [NAME] => Diesel
            )

        [32] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 92
                [NAME] => Dior
            )

        [33] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 94
                [NAME] => Disko
            )

        [34] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 96
                [NAME] => Eleo
            )

        [35] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 38
                [NAME] => Emporio Armani
            )

        [36] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 62
                [NAME] => Emporio Armani 6721
            )

        [37] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 98
                [NAME] => Fashion
            )

        [38] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 250
                [NAME] => Ferragamo
            )

        [39] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 100
                [NAME] => Ferrari
            )

        [40] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 102
                [NAME] => Fhulun
            )

        [41] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 104
                [NAME] => Fler de lis
            )

        [42] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 106
                [NAME] => Franck Muller
            )

        [43] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 108
                [NAME] => Frank Muller
            )

        [44] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 110
                [NAME] => Friend
            )

        [45] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 112
                [NAME] => Fuerdanni
            )

        [46] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 114
                [NAME] => Geneva
            )

        [47] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 116
                [NAME] => Givenchy
            )

        [48] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 118
                [NAME] => Goer
            )

        [49] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 120
                [NAME] => Golldis
            )

    )

[next] => 50
[total] => 155
[time] => Array
    (
        [start] => 1560340785.9161
        [finish] => 1560340785.9546
        [duration] => 0.038478851318359
        [processing] => 0.011644840240479
        [date_start] => 2019-06-12T14:59:45+03:00
        [date_finish] => 2019-06-12T14:59:45+03:00
    )

 )
```

там есть `[next] => 50` как вывести следующие записи ?

```
$catalog_product = CRest::call('crm.productsection.list', [
'order' => ["NAME" => "ASC"] ,
//'filter' => ["SECTION_ID" => '272' ],
'select' => [ "ID", "NAME" ]]
);
```

Извиняюсь если не совсем корректно задан вопрос.

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос

Comment: Есть массив там установлен лимит выводить по 50 а как вывести следующие 50 это bitrex24

Comment: Ну, вероятней всего это пагинация завётся... Вам надо посмотреть как как вообще формируется этот массив.. Вероятней всего там надо лимиты менять в запросе

Comment: там в целом-то в примерах написано, что `if(result.more()) result.next()`, а как сразу получить с нужным смещением не понятно. какое то странное описание апи, даже параметров не описано никаких. или 1С он везде такой ущербный?

Comment: При чем тут 1с это же обычный битрикс.

Comment: @u_mulder  Может у вас пример есть как это делается буду благодарен

Comment: Вероятно вам поможет вот это https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/api_d7/bitrix/main/entity/datamanager/getlist.php так как все гетлисты в д7 все-таки от этого пляшут. Если нет - то надо копать глубже. И да - документация ущербна.

Comment: @ u_mulder Спасибо

Comment: Может кому-то пригодиться у bitrix24 есть параметр `start` с ним можно посмотреть, например `'order' => ["NAME" => "ASC"] ,
        //'filter' => ["SECTION_ID" => '272' ],
        'select' => [ "ID", "NAME" ],
        'start'  => 50`

Comment: Вы можете оформить ответ и даже принять его.